# Recursively enumerable in a one-to-one manner

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

I've encountered a statement like this (I hope it's correct, if not, let me know)

> The sets that can be recursively enumerated in a one-to-one manner are the infinite recursively enumerated sets.

But I don't really understand what the infiniteness condition has to do with one-to-one enumeration. First, to enumerate a set $A$ in a one-to-one manner amounts to (from what I understand) having an enumerator that outputs all the elements of $A$ (and only them) exactly once. Now, if $A$ is recursively enumerable, we have an access to the code of its enumerator. Can't we just modify that code by saying "before outputing something, check whether this 'something' had already been spit out, and if so, don't output it for a second time"? I don't see how infiniteness is used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our "enumerator" is assumed to have domain $\mathbb{N}$. Since there are no injections of any complexity from $\mathbb{N}$ to a finite set, the infinitude requirement is essential.

The precise theorem is:

> Suppose $A$ is an infinite r.e. set. Then there is a total computable injective function $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with $ran(f)=A$.

Comment: One of the definitions of c.e. sets on Wikipedia is "There is an algorithm that enumerates the members of $S$." This doesn't say anything about the "domain of the enumerator". Is this information still encoded in the Wikipedia's definition somehow?

Comment: @user634426 That's just in the introductory section, and is a bit vague. When it comes to precise definitions, the wiki page is [very careful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set#Equivalent_formulations): the two definitions along these lines it gives are "the range of a partial computable function" and "either empty or the range of a total computable function." Each of these is correct; we could add injectivity to the former, but not the latter. Going back to the introduction, "algorithm" there means "**partial** computable function."

Comment: Well, I'm still a bit confused. Some textbooks take the definition I mentioned as a primary definition (e.g. see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmIPl.png)). They don't specify by which algorithm it can be enumerated. Then they prove the equivalence of this "vague" definition to other definitions: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzRpW.png). Does this mean these proofs are wrong? Also, I'm not sure why you boldfaced "partial".

Comment: @user634426 Those texts presumably define "algorithm" in a precise way at some previous stage. If they don't, then those definitions are not entirely precise, which is unfortunate. But this is just a minor annoyance: as I've said above, replace "algorithm" with "partial computable function" to get a totally rigorous definition.

Comment: [Here's how they "define" algorithms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leyqJ.png). Okay, I'll think of algorithms in the way you said.

Comment: @user634426 What book is that? That's ... unfortunate.

Comment: "Computable Functions" by N. K. Vereshchagin and A. Shen.